# Creating a Firebug Object Selector Tool in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying a create a facility (using jquery) to be able to select elements on a page, much the same way as the selector tool in Firebug works. Where you can toggle the tool and then rollover the page and each element hovered on to is given a border. The tool only needs to work (for now) on span, div and img elements. Here is my code so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });



    $("img").hover(function() { //On Mouse Over
        //Collect current border information and create red border.
        var currentBorder = new Array();
        currentBorder[0] = $(this).css('border-top-color');
        currentBorder[1] = $(this).css('border-top-width');
        currentBorder[2] = $(this).css('border-top-style');
        currentBorder[3] = $(this).css('border-left-color');
        currentBorder[4] = $(this).css('border-left-width');
        currentBorder[5] = $(this).css('border-left-style');
        currentBorder[6] = $(this).css('border-right-color');
        currentBorder[7] = $(this).css('border-right-width');
        currentBorder[8] = $(this).css('border-right-style');
        currentBorder[9] = $(this).css('border-bottom-color');
        currentBorder[10] = $(this).css('border-bottom-width');
        currentBorder[11] = $(this).css('border-bottom-style');
        $(this).css('border', 'solid thin red');
        $(this).css('cursor', 'crosshair');

    }, function() { //On Mouse Out
        //Return border to previous state.
        $(this).css('border', 'none');
        $(this).css("border-top-color", currentBorder[0]);
        $(this).css("border-top-width", currentBorder[1]);
        $(this).css("border-top-style", currentBorder[2]);
        $(this).css("border-left-color", currentBorder[3]);
        $(this).css("border-left-width", currentBorder[4]);
        $(this).css("border-left-style", currentBorder[5]);
        $(this).css("border-right-color", currentBorder[6]);
        $(this).css("border-right-width", currentBorder[7]);
        $(this).css("border-right-style", currentBorder[8]);
        $(this).css("border-bottom-color", currentBorder[9]);
        $(this).css("border-bottom-width", currentBorder[10]);
        $(this).css("border-bottom-style", currentBorder[11]);
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
    });

    var currentColor;
    $("span").hover(function() { //On Mouse Over

        //Collect current border information and create red border.

        currentColor = $(this).css('color');
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
        $(this).css('cursor', 'crosshair');


    }, function() { //On Mouse Out

        //Return border to previous state.      
        $(this).css('color', currentColor);
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default');

    });








        $("div").hover(function() { //On Mouse Over
        //Collect current border information and create red border.
        var currentBorder = new Array();
        currentBorder[0] = $(this).css('border-top-color');
        currentBorder[1] = $(this).css('border-top-width');
        currentBorder[2] = $(this).css('border-top-style');
        currentBorder[3] = $(this).css('border-left-color');
        currentBorder[4] = $(this).css('border-left-width');
        currentBorder[5] = $(this).css('border-left-style');
        currentBorder[6] = $(this).css('border-right-color');
        currentBorder[7] = $(this).css('border-right-width');
        currentBorder[8] = $(this).css('border-right-style');
        currentBorder[9] = $(this).css('border-bottom-color');
        currentBorder[10] = $(this).css('border-bottom-width');
        currentBorder[11] = $(this).css('border-bottom-style');
        $(this).css('border', 'solid thin red');

    }, function() { //On Mouse Out
        //Return border to previous state.
        $(this).css('border', 'none');
        $(this).css("border-top-color", currentBorder[0]);
        $(this).css("border-top-width", currentBorder[1]);
        $(this).css("border-top-style", currentBorder[2]);
        $(this).css("border-left-color", currentBorder[3]);
        $(this).css("border-left-width", currentBorder[4]);
        $(this).css("border-left-style", currentBorder[5]);
        $(this).css("border-right-color", currentBorder[6]);
        $(this).css("border-right-width", currentBorder[7]);
        $(this).css("border-right-style", currentBorder[8]);
        $(this).css("border-bottom-color", currentBorder[9]);
        $(this).css("border-bottom-width", currentBorder[10]);
        $(this).css("border-bottom-style", currentBorder[11]);

    });


});
```

At the moment, the code binds a listener to every instance of these type of objects, on hover it stores the css styling in a var, and turns it red. Then on hover out, it restores the previous css attributes and ther values. So far, this seems to work, but my onlu problem is on a page that looks like this:

```
<div>
     <span>This is my first span</span>
     <span>This is my second span</span>
     <span>This is my third span</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that, when rolling over the spans, the hover event triggers for both the span and the surrounding div. After a while just staring at the screen, i'm stumped.

I'd appreciate just suggestions on a better way to approach this, I'll post the final code on here when i've got it working correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding the following to each listener

for mouseover:

```
 $(this).parent().trigger('mouseout');
```

for mouseout:

```
 $(this).parent().trigger('mouseover');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want mousing over an element to not bubble up, use `stopPropagation()`.

```
$('img').hover(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
}, ...);
```

A better way may be to attach an event handler to the document, and use `event.which` to determine what started the event.

```
$(document).hover(function(event) {
   var element = event.which;
}, ...);
```

Comment: stopPropagation isn't so useful in this instance, as once you mouse reaches the inner element, its already fired the function for the outer elements hover. The script needs to trigger the hover(out) functions for all other objects on the page.